# TensorFlow - Batch normalization failing on regression?

Tags: tensorflow, regression, batch-normalization

I'm using TensorFlow for a multi-target regression problem. Specifically, in a convolutional network with pixel-wise labeling with the input being an image and the label being a "heat-map" where each pixel has a float value. More specifically, the ground truth labeling for each pixel is lower bounded by zero, and, while technically having no upper bound, usually gets no larger than 1e-2.

Without batch normalization, the network is able to give a reasonable heat-map prediction. With batch normalization, the network takes much long to get to reasonable loss value, and the best it does is making every pixel the average value. This is using the `tf.contrib.layers` [`conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/conv2d) and [`batch_norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/conv2d) methods, with the `batch_norm` being passed to the `conv2d`'s `normalization_fn` (or not in the case of no batch normalization). I had briefly tried batch normalization on another (single value) regression network, and had trouble then as well (though, I hadn't tested that as extensively). Is there a problem using batch normalization on regression problems in general? Is there a common solution?

If not, what could be some causes batch normalization failing on such an application? I've attempted a variety of initializations, learning rates, etc. I would expect the final layer (which of course does not use batch normalization) could use weights to scale the output of the penultimate layer to the appropriate regression values. Failing that, I removed batch norm from that layer, but with no improvement. I've attempted a small classification problem using batch normalization and saw no problem there, so it seems reasonable that it could be due somehow to the nature of the regression problem, but I don't know how that could cause such a drastic difference. Is batch normalization known to have trouble on regression problems?

Comment: I am running through the same problem. Have you solved the problem? Did you find any solution. Thanks

Comment: this might be the reason: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/37466/43077

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is in the labels. Batch norm will scale all input values between 0 and 1. If the labels are not scaled to a similar range the task will be more difficult. This is because it requires the NN to learn values of a different scale.

By removing the batch norm from the penultimate layer, the task may be improved slightly, but you are still requiring an NN layer to learn to downscale values of its input while subsequently normalizing back to the range 0 - 1 (opposite to your objective).

To solve this problem, apply a 0 - 1 scaler to the labels such that your upper bound is no longer 1e-2. During inference, transform the predictions back with the same function to get the actual prediction.